# Jenkins pipeline - refering to SSH Keys in ansible and Terraform

Tags: azure, jenkins, ssh, ansible

I have a ansible playbook which refers to ssh key data for adding the public key to the authorized_host file when it is created, here is an extract.

```
  vars:
    vm1: 
      ssh_key_var: '{{ ssh_key_data }}'

  tasks:
      - name: Create VM
        azure_rm_virtualmachine:
          resource_group: '{{ resource_group1.name }}'
          name: '{{ vm1.name }}'
          vm_size: '{{ vm1.size }}'
          admin_username: '{{ vm1.admin_username }}'
          ssh_password_enabled: false
          ssh_public_keys:
            - path: '/home/{{ vm1.admin_username }}/.ssh/authorized_keys'
              key_data: '{{ vm1.ssh_key_var }}'
          network_interfaces: '{{ network_interface1.name }}'
          image: '{{ vm1.image }}'
```

Normally this is pretty straight forward - I'd run on my laptop and have key locally, maybe get the data referred to as a file.

I tried running the playbook with secret text in a jenkins pipeline as using an environmental variable secret text "AZURE_AUTHORIZED_KEY" for the public key, which I store in credentials:

```
   stage('Deploy server') {
        agent {
            docker { image 'my_ansible_container:latest' }
        }
        environment {
            AZURE_CLIENT_ID         = credentials('AZURE_CLIENT_ID_ANSIBLE')
            AZURE_SECRET            = credentials('AZURE_SECRET_ANSIBLE')
            AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID   = credentials('AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID_ANSIBLE')
            AZURE_TENANT            = credentials('AZURE_TENANT_ANSIBLE')
            AUTHORIZED_KEY          = credentials('AZURE_AUTHORIZED_KEY')
        }
        steps {
            // deploy server
            sh "ansible-playbook playbook.yml --extravars \"ssh_key_data=${AUTHORIZED_KEY}\""
        }
    }
```

When I add the public key as a var in the playbook it all works fine, but I dont want to store keys in the repo, even if they are public keys and it's a private repo.

When I import as env_var it does not seem to take the value and 'cascade' it in to the vars as expected.  Anyone have a solution to this kind of problem - is my approach wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong, expect typing errors, bit of closing quotes also.  Here is the syntax for those who may be interested.  Note I am using this as a intermediate solution where I want to move secrets out of jenkins and into something like hashicorp vault.

I also renamed some of my env vars to be a bit more, *representative*:

```
         }
        environment {
            AZURE_CLIENT_ID         = credentials('AZURE_CLIENT_ID_ANSIBLE')
            AZURE_SECRET            = credentials('AZURE_SECRET_ANSIBLE')
            AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID   = credentials('AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID_ANSIBLE')
            AZURE_TENANT            = credentials('AZURE_TENANT_ANSIBLE')
            AUTHORIZED_KEY          = credentials('AZURE_AUTHORIZED_KEY')
            AUTHORIZED_PASSWORD     = credentials('AZURE_AUTHORIZED_PASSWORD')
        }
        steps {
            // deploy a boot strap server
            sh "ansible-playbook playbook.yml \
                    --extra-var 'admin_password_var=${AUTHORIZED_PASSWORD}' \
                    --extra-var 'ssh_public_key_var=${AUTHORIZED_KEY}'"
        }
```

and an extract of the playbook

```
     vars: 
       vm1: 
         admin_password: '{{ admin_password_var }}'
         ssh_public_key: '{{ ssh_public_key_var }}'  

      - name: Create VM
        azure_rm_virtualmachine:
          resource_group: '{{ resource_group1.name }}'
          name: '{{ vm1.name }}'
          vm_size: '{{ vm1.size }}'
          admin_username: '{{ vm1.admin_username }}'
          admin_password: '{{ vm1.admin_password }}'
          ssh_password_enabled: false
          ssh_public_keys:
            - path: '/home/{{ vm1.admin_username }}/.ssh/authorized_keys'
             key_data: '{{ vm1.ssh_public_key }}'
          network_interfaces: '{{ network_interface1.name }}'
          image: '{{ vm1.image }}'
```

Note I have chosen variables that may appear duplicative, but I prefer the approach given it allows me to trace back the source and not get confused which one is being used.

There may be other approaches, but this is a working one, and simple as well; which strikes me as an attractive combination!

Comment: How did you set credentials as env variables? I am trying to do similar thing in my pipeline but I am getting errors. I am trying to do something like this:


    environment {
            ARM_CLIENT_ID = credentials('AZURE_CLIENT_ID')
            ARM_CLIENT_SECRET = credentials('AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET')
            ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID = credentials('AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID')
            ARM_TENANT_ID = credentials('AZURE_TENANT_ID')
    }

Comment: Do it in the environment block   environment {
            AZURE_CLIENT_ID         = credentials('AZURE_CLIENT_ID_ANSIBLE')
            AZURE_SECRET            = credentials('AZURE_SECRET_ANSIBLE')
            AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID   = credentials('AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID_ANSIBLE')
            AZURE_TENANT            = credentials('AZURE_TENANT_ANSIBLE')
            AUTHORIZED_KEY          = credentials('AZURE_AUTHORIZED_KEY')
            AUTHORIZED_PASSWORD     = credentials('AZURE_AUTHORIZED_PASSWORD')